# Difficulty navigating SOAP client WSDL with PHP functions

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am experimenting with a public SOAP API in preparation for testing an internal SOAP API that we are working on at work. I am running into problems dealing with automatically associating method names with parameter names.

More specifically I am testing against http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL and what I am trying to do is write a function I can use in Behat so that our QA people can easily create new scenarios specifying new functions (as they are created) without me writing a new function every time.

To do this I built a function wrapper for SoapClient::__soapCall(). I have been able to get calls to specific functions to work such as this:

```
<?php
public function iGetAQuoteFor($symbol) {
    $response = $this->client->GetQuote(array('symbol' => $symbol));
    $quote = simplexml_load_string($response->GetQuoteResult)->Stock;
    echo "Quote:\n" . print_r($quote, true) . "\n";
}
?>
```

So obviously I need to identify the parameter I am sending to the SOAP service for it to be effective. But to do that I need to be able to map the function name to the option names. I have tried processing the WSDL with SimpleXML, but I am having a difficult time navigating the results of that. I have tried a bunch of different methods and made some headway when I used the SimpleXML function 'children' and specified the 'wsdl' namespace. But what I get below that isn't any better.

Here is my soap call function (written as a Behat context):

```
/**
 * Calls a specific SOAP function (defined in the WSDL).
 *
 * @param string $functionName
 * @param string $options (optional, no implemented yet)
 *
 * @Given /^I make a SOAP call to "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/
 * @Given /^I make a SOAP call to "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iMakeASOAPCallTo($functionName, $passedOptions = NULL) {
    //Deal with the options
    $options = array($passedOptions);

    if (stristr($passedOptions, ',')) {
        $options = explode(',', $passedOptions);
    }
    else if (empty($passedOptions)) {
        $options = array();
    }

    //Also should try to figure out how to match the function call to the option wrapper
    #Function placeholder

    //Attempt to make the call
    try {
        $result = $this->client->__soapCall($functionName, $options);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to call SOAP function.");
    }

    //Process the result
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $result = $this->decodeSOAPResult($functionName, $result);

        if (!empty($result)) {
            echo "        It returns:\n" . print_r($result, true) . "\n";
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid result from function call.");
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Failed result or exception from function call.");
    }
}
```

And this is my function that attempts to get the schema details after establishing the connection to the soap service.

```
private function buildSchemaDetails() {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($this->soapURL);
    echo "\n" . print_r($xml, true) . "\n";

    echo "For the ns:\n";
    $element = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
    echo "\n" . print_r($element, true) . "\n";

    $element = $xml->children('wsdl', true)->types->children();
    echo "\n" . print_r($element, true) . "\n";

    die();
}
```

As you can see I have some testing code in there. It is ugly right now, but I need to figure out how to process this. If anyone knows of a tool that does all of this for me ahead of time that would be awesome.

Essentially what I want to be able to do is identify the parameters to a function before I make any attempts to call it. If the function has only one parameter then I would like to just map the variable entered to the one parameter name based on the function I am calling and then call it.

This is useful within Behat when writing features and scenarios because then it allows me to write a Gherkin-style line such as 'Then I make a SOAP call to "GetQuote" with "GOOG"' and not having to worry about specifying the name of the parameter. In the case of this WSDL I found it to be a bit ridiculous that couldn't just pass in the one variable and be done with it. I have seen anther SOAP service where I didn't have to specify the parameter name.

So being able to understand the call structure is key to simplifying all of this.

Comment: Are you concerned about indexed or named parameters here or both? ([*Why does the order of SOAP parameters matter in PHP SOAP, and how to fix it?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4222319/367456)). Then from quickly scanning your problem might be related to XML namespaces. It's not really clear to me from your question what that processing should result into. You might want to edit the question a little and add some example that shows what you're trying to achieve with *buildSchemaDetails*.

Comment: Here is a snapshot of the XML as well in case the URI changes: https://gist.github.com/hakre/5821049

Comment: I wonder if using `classmap` would serve you better. Have you investigated that option?

Comment: I am not familiar with classmap. I will look into that.